# PANDAS Within Category Normalization

Tags: pandas, categorical-data, normalization

I'm want to normalize sales data of multiple point of sales (POS), Products and weeks. The dataframe looks like this:

```
    pos product sales   week
0   1   car     250      1
1   2   tank    400      2
2   2   car     300      1
3   1   tank    500      2
```

The goal is to normalize the data between 0,1 for each point of sale and product, e.g the minimum and maximum relate to the minimum and maximum of sales within a specific product and a specific point of sale. I guess I can just create a column for each combination (example below) and then normalize each column but I'm looking for a more elegant solution.

```
    pos     1         2
    product car tank  car   tank
week                
1           250  0    300     0
2           0    500    0   400
```

Thanks, 
Al

Answer (score 1):

As you require it to be per week vs point of sale, you have to group them by those columns. Once grouped, you could run do the standard split-apply-combine, where based on the grouping, you get splits or groups, you can apply a function that normalizes data in this group and then you combine all the groups back.

You can read about it more here : https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html

Comment: Hi Nischal, 
Thanks for your help. I'm rather new in the field and find it hard to understand. Can you focus me please?

Comment: He provided a link that is helpful - maybe start there and "get back" to us with questions?